# MySQLdb.Connect raises.OperationalError: Can't connect to MySQL server

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, mysql-python

Using multithreading.dummy.Pool and MySQLdb for make queries to MySQL database. Getting Error:

```
    _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on
 '127.0.0.1' (10055)")
```

Can anyone help to solve this problem?

Thanks All.

P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

**UPD:**
Some code:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
def worker1(target):
    con = mdb.connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DB, charset='utf8')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("insert into links values('"+target[0]+"', '"+target[1]+"',     '"+target[2]+"','"+target[3]+"')")
    con.commit()
    con.close()

def main():
    pool = ThreadPool(200)
    pool.map(worker1, links)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Tal Kremerman, I am running server on my computer, port 3306. On my notebook all works perfect on ThreadPool size 8. On server machine with Core i-7 my script returned this error. For catch this error on my notebook i made ThreadPool size 200 and changed max_connection to 2000

Comment: So you have mysql running both on your computer and on the server? And if you run the connect method outside of the worker and multiprocessing context it works?

Comment: Wait one minute please. Will try.

Comment: _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

Answer (score 0):

MySQL defaults to allowing 100 connections at once. The code is spawning 200 threads, each (tries to) connect to the database.  Thus, 100 will fail.

Consider using a connection pool.  Or, tell MySQL to allow more connections at a time:

http://major.io/2007/01/24/increase-mysql-connection-limit/

Comment: On my pc max_connections=2000